# Placement of an LED in a circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, electric-current, electrical-resistance, light-emitting-diodes

When an LED is connected in a circuit it needs a resistor so that excess current does not pass through it, but when a resistor is placed after the LED, it works the same as when the resistor is placed before the LED. Why? It has a high amount of current flowing through it as the resistor opposes the current after it flows through the LED?

Comment: According to you, the current at one of the terminals of the resistor is lesser than the other terminal? That is not the case. The same current flows irrespective of the location of the resistor.

Comment: I mean, that as the electrons reach the resistor the flow of current decreases at that point, right?

Comment: Think of what happens on a wide freeway when there's an accident ahead that closes many of the lanes.  The flow of traffic _before_ the accident is decreased, even though that traffic has not been through the accident site yet.

Comment: I dont see the fact here, till the electrons near the accident site dont get the energy to travel (which they will get after electrons passing through the LED first) how will elctrons know??

Comment: My circuit can be represnted as +---led---w-----gnd

Comment: I want to know what happens exactly inside (to the elctrons in the first go)(in the above comment w represents resistor)

Comment: You're not familiar with [Kirchhoff's current law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_current_law_.28KCL.29)?

Comment: *"I mean, that as the electrons reach the resistor the flow of current decreases at that point, right?"* - no, that's not a correct understanding of resistors or Kirchhoff's current law.

Comment: Ok maybe that part of Kirchoffs law confuses me alot.. where is it applicable in my question

Comment: Total-resistance of  series combined resistors remains the same, if we re-order the resistors. While using the LED only in forward-bias, and a given resistor, we can imagine the LED as another resistor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ok maybe that part of Kirchoffs law confuses me alot.. where is it
>   applicable in my question

Kirchhoff's circuit laws are fundamental to (lumped element) circuit theory.

In the case of Kirchhoff's current law (KCL), which is essentially that the sum of currents entering a node (junction of two or more circuit elements) equals the sum of currents leaving the node, we learn that series connected circuit elements have identical current through.

That is, according to KCL, *all* of the current *out of* the LED is *in to* the resistor.  If you were to swap their order, then *all* of the current *out of* the resistor is *in to* the LED.  In either case, both the LED and resistor have identical current through.

What then does the resistor do? Since the voltage across the (forward biased) LED is essentially constant over a wide range of current through, the voltage across the resistor is essentially fixed.  Thus, by Ohm's law, the series current is determined by the *value* of the resistance.

---

From a comment:

> how do the electrons know that there is resitance ahead 'go slow'?

I directly quote from Griffith's "Introduction to Electrodynamics, 4th Edition", section 7.1.2, page 303:

> If you think about a typical electric circuit - a battery hooked up to
>   a light bulb, say (Fig 7.7) - a perplexing question arises:  In
>   practice, the *current is the same all the way around the loop*; why
>   is this the case, when the only obvious driving force is inside the
>   battery?  Off hand, you might expect a large current in the battery
>   and none at all in the lamp.  Who's doing the pushing, in the rest of
>   the circuit, and how does it happen that this push is exactly right to
>   produce the same current in each segment?  What's more, given that the
>   charges in a typical wire move (literally) at a a *snail's* pace, (see
>   Prob. 5.20), why doesn't it take half an hour for the current to reach
>   the light bulb?  How do all the charges know to start moving at the
>   same instant?
>
> *Answer*:  If the current were *not* the same all the way around (for instance, during the first split second after the switch is closed),
>   then charge would be piling up somewhere, and - here's the crucial
>   point - the electric field of this accumulating charge is in such a
>   directions as to even out the flow.  Suppose, for instance, that the
>   current *into* the bend in Fig. 7.8 is greater than the current *out*.
>   Then charge piles up at the "knee", and this produces a field aiming
>   *away* from the kink.  This field *opposes* the current flowing in (slowing it down) and *promotes* the current flowing out (speeding it
>   up) until these currents are equal, at which point there is no further
>   accumulation of charge, and equilibrium is established.  It's a
>   beautiful system, automatically self-correcting to keep the current
>   uniform, and it does it all so quickly that, in practice, you can
>   safely assume the current is the same all around the circuit, even in
>   systems that oscillate at radio frequencies.

Comment: Then why is the current same through out, how is it same, how do the electrons know that there is resitance ahead 'go slow'?

Comment: @user5444075, electrons are charged and thus respond to electric fields.  Roughly speaking, If the current out of the LED towards the resistor were too large, charge would 'build up' there and the resulting electric field would act to *reduce* the flow out of the LED until equilibrium (steady state) is eventually reached.

Comment: over here, what do you mean by equilibrium, won't this go on?

Comment: @user5444075, I'm not interested in hashing this out in the comments.  I recommend that you ask about steady state in a separate question.

Comment: Ok thats not a problem @Alfred Centauri, so I can now say that there is an electric field set up in the circuit and the repulsive forces repel electrons hence slowing down the flow throughout, correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: @user5444075, I've added a quote to my answer that you may find helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Alfred Centauri  and others for giving me their time.. the answer above misses one point about the driving force for the electrons further in the circuit. Is it because of electrons transferring energy by colliding with each other?